# Rails 5.02 parameters unpermitted error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, form-helpers

In my project I have three models Product, Page and Pictures. Product `has_one :page` and `has_many :pictures` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :page, :pictures`.

In `products_controller` I have added `product_params` as:

```
def product_params
 params.require(:product).permit(:name, :model, :price, page_attributes: [:content], pictures_attributes: [:file])
end
```

But when I submit form `Product` is created but `Picture` and `Page` is not saved.
The console shows message `picture and page unpermitted`

What can be the reason ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**Some times we forget syntax**

In form page while generating fields for nested attributes did a little mistake that took whole day.

Just following changes in form solved problem.

```
<%= fields_for(product.page) do |fp| %>
```

changed to

```
 <%= fields_for(:page) do |fp| %>
```

and 
    <%= fields_for(product.pictures) do |fpr| %>
changed to

```
 <%= fields_for(:pictures) do |fpr| %>
```

We need to know here we always need to use symbol instead of object.